# How to get the specific name of a user from realtime firebase to html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table to display the list of created accounts from my firebase. Everything is working fine except for the retrieval of each name from each table row when the account icon is clicked. I already have a method for the retrieval but I keep on having the "Uncaught ReferenceError: gety is not defined:" error.

Here is my script code:

```js
<script type="module">
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-analytics.js";

        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

        import {getDatabase, ref, child, onValue, get } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js";
        const db = getDatabase();

        var std = 0;
      var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody1");
        function AddItem(name,email,registration, status) {
          let trow = document.createElement("tr");
          let td1 = document.createElement("td");
          let td2 = document.createElement("td");
          let td3 = document.createElement("td");
          let td4 = document.createElement("td");
          let td5 = document.createElement("td");
          let td6 = document.createElement("td");
          let td7 = document.createElement("td");
          let td8 = document.createElement("td");
          let td9 = document.createElement("td");

          td1.innerHTML = ++std;
          td2.innerHTML = name;
          td3.innerHTML = email;
          td4.innerHTML = registration;
          td5.innerHTML = status;
          

        function gety(){
          var namey = document.getElementById(name).value
          var user_ref = db.ref('users/' + namey)
          user_ref.on('value', function(snapshot){
            var data = snapshot.val()
            alert(data.name)
          })
        }
        
          td6.innerHTML = "<a href='viewID.html'><button type='button' name='button' class='viewIDbtn'>View ID</button></a>";
          td7.innerHTML = "<center> <td class='tago'> <a href='#viewDriversAcct.html' id='view' onclick='gety()'><img src='images/view.png' id='acct_logo'></a></td> </center>";
          td8.innerHTML = "<center> <td class='tago'> <a href='editCommutersAcct.html'><img src='images/update.png' id='update'></a></td> </center>";
          td9.innerHTML = "<td colspan='2' class='actionbtn'> <a href='#activate_action'><img src='images/checkAction.png' id='active_actionbtns'></a><a href='#deactivate_action'><img src='images/Xaction.png' id='actionbtns'></a></td>";

          
          trow.appendChild(td1);
          trow.appendChild(td2);
          trow.appendChild(td3);
          trow.appendChild(td4);
          trow.appendChild(td5);
          trow.appendChild(td6);
          trow.appendChild(td7);
          trow.appendChild(td8);
          trow.appendChild(td9);

          tbody.appendChild(trow);

        }

        function AddAllItems(users) {
          std=0;
          tbody.innerHTML="";
          users.forEach(element => {
            var name =element.firstName + " " + element.lastName;
            AddItem(name, element.email, element.registration,  element.status)
          });
          }

        // import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-app.js";
        // import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-analytics.js";

        // // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

       
        //getting items from firebase

        function getAllData() {
            const dbref = ref(db);
            get(child(dbref, "users"))
            .then((snapshot) => {
              var commuter = [];
              snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                commuter.push(childSnapshot.val());
              });
              AddAllItems(commuter);
            })
        }

        function getAllDataRT() {
            const dbRef = ref(db, "users");

            onValue(dbRef,(snapshot)=>{
              var commuters = [];
              snapshot.forEach(childsnapshot => {
                commuters.push(childsnapshot.val());
              });
              AddAllItems(commuters);
            })
        }

        window.onLoad = getAllDataRT();
      </script>
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>EMAIL</th>
      <th>REGISTRATION DATE</th>
      <th>STATUS</th>
      <th class="tago">ID</th>
      <th class="tago">ACCOUNT</th>
      <th class="tago">EDIT</th>
      <th class="tago">ACTION</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id ="tbody1"> </tbody>
```